# Using custom button for new Google Sign-in (javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-identity

I am migrating our code from the older Google authentication API to the new Google Sign-in stuff. What I want to do is be able to use our existing "continue with Google" button, and trigger the Google popup from there. Yes, I know there are many options for customizing the button drawn with " google.accounts.id.renderButton", but our internal registration forms have embedded buttons, and these forms are all stored in our database for some 10,000 customers. I would rather not have to re-write all their stored form data to do this. I have this initialization:

```
(async () => {
    while (!window.google || !window.google.accounts) {
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 10));
    }

    // setting up da google...
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: clientId,
        callback: handleCredentialResponse,
    });
})();
```

it would just be really nice to be able to have a function that my internal javascript could call to trigger the Google authentication popup and make the callback as defined above.  Like:

```
google.accounts.id.authenticate()
```

or something like that. Is this possible?